# Error importing map with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, osm2pgsql

I've been following this guide to setting up my own osm node.
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

I've gone trough all the compiles and configurations with no complications (twice) but in both runs I ended up with the following error

```
Using built-in tag processing pipeline
Using projection SRS 3857 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: CREATE TABLE planet_osm_point (osm_id int8,"access" text,"addr:housename" text,"addr:housenumber" text,"addr:interpolation" text,"admin_level" text,"aerialway" text,"aeroway" text,"amenity" text,"area" text,"barrier" text,"bicycle" text,"brand" text,"bridge" text,"boundary" text,"building" text,"capital" text,"construction" text,"covered" text,"culvert" text,"cutting" text,"denomination" text,"disused" text,"ele" text,"embankment" text,"foot" text,"generator:source" text,"harbour" text,"highway" text,"historic" text,"horse" text,"intermittent" text,"junction" text,"landuse" text,"layer" text,"leisure" text,"lock" text,"man_made" text,"military" text,"motorcar" text,"name" text,"natural" text,"office" text,"oneway" text,"operator" text,"place" text,"poi" text,"population" text,"power" text,"power_source" text,"public_transport" text,"railway" text,"ref" text,"religion" text,"route" text,"service" text,"shop" text,"sport" text,"surface" text,"toll" text,"tourism" text,"tower:type" text,"tunnel" text,"water" text,"waterway" text,"wetland" text,"width" text,"wood" text,"z_order" int4,way geometry(POINT,3857) ) WITH ( autovacuum_enabled = FALSE ) failed: ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 1: ... text,"width" text,"wood" text,"z_order" int4,way geometry(P...
```

I've gone trough the database configuration again and everything seems to be in order. Any ideas how to debug/fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `type "geometry" does not exist` part clearly states that you have no postgis extension installed.

Maybe you missed/forgot following part of the tutorial on creating extension in postgres db?

> substitute your username for *username* below

Comment: I've done the following:

CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO username;
ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO username;

Comment: Upon checking every step again I've noticed I created the extension geometry under the wrong database. The solution was simply to connect to the database (in my case named gis) before creating the extension. Thanks!